# NetBeans 7.0.1 C++ - using a static library, 'undefined reference to'

Tags: c++, static-libraries, netbeans7.0

I'm trying to write a program, for an exercise, that uses a static library - .a and .h files provided by the school. I followed my logic and answers I saw here, and added the .a file in the project's Properties -> Build -> Linker -> libraries. The program #includes the file with "file.h", and all files are in the same folder.

Although everything appears to be in order and the console shows that the .a file is added to the linker command, I get 'undefined reference to (functions from library)' errors.

Please help!

Comment: Can you obtain and post the full compiler command-line invocation?

Comment: @MartinhoFernandes This is the jist of it.
I removed the full path from the object files, but that's it. g++.exe -o PrintQ2.o Q2.o RandomDouble.o randomaelf64.a -static

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html) about what parameters you have to pass during the linking